# Make BarCharts from file CSV

Tags: excel

I have a xls file and the data are:

```
Hour    Expenses1   Expenses2
17:50   1500    2000
17:55   1750    1830
18:00   1980    1330
```

There are three columns and I need  import the file and plot a bar graph that data.

I could help with this issue

Comment: Your title says CSV and the body of the question says xls.  Have you looked at the documentation for `Import`?

Answer (score 1):

You could press f1 and look up `Import`. Your dataset is small enough that you could just copy and paste it manually into mathematica. Look up the documentation for `BarChart` to adjust the colors to your liking.

```
BarChart[{{1500, 1750, 1980}, {2000, 1830, 1330}},ChartLabels -> {"17:50", "17:55", "8:00"}]


Insert[Grid[{{"Hour", "Expenses1", "Expenses2"}, {"17:50", 1500, 
2000}, {"17:55", 1750, 1830}, {"8:00", 1980, 
1330}}], {Background -> {None, {GrayLevel[0.7], {White}}}, 
 Dividers -> {Black, {2 -> Black}}, Frame -> True, 
 Spacings -> {2, {2, {0.7}, 2}}}, 2]
```

[image]

[image]